# Magento 1.9 checkout page CSS is disturbed after clearing the cache

Tags: magento-1.9, css

Last night I cleared the cache of magento under the magento directory:

```
/var/cache/
```

After which the css on checkout page is disturbed now. I try to rollback my changes but still its not working any idea why this is happening.

Only checkout page is effected rest of the website is working properly.

URL: http://54.191.132.18/checkout/onepage/

[image]

Comment: try flush css cache and then clear all cache. The hard reload your browser

Comment: I did that but still the problem exist.

Comment: Console shows "*Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4*" error. your current jQuery version is 1.7.2.  Or bootstrap CSS overriding your CSS.

Comment: but what's the solution for it.. Its kind of a warning I guess.

Comment: yes,  it is a warning, but you need to check your bootstrap CSS it 's overriding your basic CSS for some element.

Comment: @kunj is there a way that I can check this. I tried by myself but wasn't able to do it.

Comment: I am going to add in the answer.

Comment: @PranjalPrakashSrivastava. did you install any extention recently in your site?

Comment: @PranjalPrakashSrivastava , remove css from your header in checkout:

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

Comment: @ChiragRajput thanks a lot you saved my day.

Comment: @PranjalPrakashSrivastava , Enjoy Buddy :)

Answer (score 3):

This happens due to conflict of _config/grid_default_de.css and https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css on checkout page.
Do one thing change the priority of the CSS means bootstrap.min.css should come before grid_default_de.css.

Answer (score 1):

I have attached two images for before changed in `.container` CSS class and after changed `.container` CSS class. You need to override some CSS class in your `styles.css` file or remove bootstrap CSS file from the checkout page.

[image: after changed in .container css class]

[image: before changed in .container css class]